# How to disable html link in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to disable html link in cakephp, I have searched for the solution and found 
array('escape' => false) for disabling link but it's not working, My Code is

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Advance Item Pricing'), array('controller' => 'ItemPrices','action' => 'edit', $itemid),array('target'=>'_blank'));
```

If anybody knows the answer please suggest me proper solution.

Comment: use array('target'=>'_blank', 'onclick' => 'return false')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Advance Item Pricing'), array('controller' => 'ItemPrices','action' => 'edit', $itemid),array('target'=>'_blank', 'disabled' => 'disabled'));
```

have you tried this code?

or

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Advance Item Pricing'), array('controller' => 'ItemPrices','action' => 'edit', $itemid),array('target'=>'_blank', 'onclick' => 'return false'));
```

or

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Advance Item Pricing'), array('controller' => 'ItemPrices','action' => 'edit', $itemid),array('target'=>'_blank', 'onclick' => 'javascript:void(0)'));
```

Answer (score 2):

By default you can't disable link by HTML.

### javascript way

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Advance Item Pricing'), array('controller' => 'ItemPrices','action' => 'edit', $itemid),array('target'=>'_blank', 'onclick' => 'return false'));
```

### CSS way

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Advance Item Pricing'), array('controller' => 'ItemPrices','action' => 'edit', $itemid),array('target'=>'_blank', 'style' => 'pointer-events : none; cursor : default;'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it. It work for me

```
 echo $this->Html->link(__('Advance Item Pricing'), array('controller' => 'ItemPrices','action' => 'edit', $itemid),array('disabled' => 'disabled'));
```